# SSRS report with stored procedure Dataset and aggregation by month - how to handle "empty" months?

Tags: sql-server, date, reporting-services, aggregation, ssrs-2014

I have a SSRS report which calls a stored procedure to return a two columns dataset - one column is a `Date` and the other is a calculated column I created to show the month in the format `MMM-YYYY`.

Using this dataset I have created an aggregated bar chart report which shows the number of records per month for each month value which has at least one record in the dataset, however I would like to be able to include on the chart any months within the range of the dataset even if they do not contain any records.

So for example, where at the moment I see the following data points on my chart:

```
Month        Count
-----        -----
Oct-2015     2
Nov-2015     5
Jan-2016     3
Feb-2016     6
```

Dec-2015 is missing because my Dataset didn't return any records for it, so I would like to be able to plot a zero Count value on the chart for this month.

Now I know how I would normally do this in SQL, with some kind of calendar table LEFT JOINed in so that I can return the months with zero counts, but can I achieve the same in SSRS with a stored procedure as the target of the main dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your grouping is on a date/time (or a number), you can make the axis type for it **Scalar**.

- Create your chart, with Count as the value and Month as the Category Group
- Right-click the grouped axis (horizontal in my example below) and go to the Axis Properties
- Change the **Axis type** to **Scalar**, and change the **Interval type** to **Months**
- Still in the axis properties, change the Number Category to `Date`, and the Type to `Jan 2000` (or use a custom format)

[image: month chart design]
[image: month chart preview]

My first instinct was to aggregate by an actual date, converted to the first of the month, instead of your `MMM-yyyy` string. However, it appears that SSRS (2008 R2 in my case) recognises text in the format `MMM-yyyy` as a valid date, so your existing procedure shouldn't need changing.

Comment: Fantastic, that's exactly what I was looking for and has worked on my report! I do have one further question now, but I will do some searching and post a separate question if necessary.